# How do I make AnyLogic recognize the Lombok plugin?

Tags: lombok, anylogic

Lombok is a great plugin that has an installer for Eclipse and IntelliJ. AnyLogic is Eclipse-based, so how do we get it to work there too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a Mac, this is the most recent process:

1. Go to Applications, right click on AnyLogic, and select Show Package Contents
2. Copy `lombok.jar` to `Contents/MacOS`
3. Edit `AnyLogic.ini`. Add `-javaagent:lombok.jar` on a line by itself after `-vmargs`

Windows and Linux are similar.

Comment: Very interesting, did not know this was possible, but I assume only applicable if all team members make use of the same plugin, since the code Lombok creates is not in the ALP file?

Comment: Yup, but if you're designing with Lombok as a key pillar you'd just enforce everyone to use it anyway, if for no other reason than their code wouldn't compile.

Comment: I am curious to know if this will be compatible with AL 9 coming the end of this year. Since it is now browser-based it might not use the Eclipse technology in the same way it used to.

Comment: As long as it has a Java backend this approach should work in some way or another. `-javaagent` AFAIK is a JVM thing and not an Eclipse thing.

Comment: On Windows it might be necessary to set it using `-javaagent:./lombok.jar'. Also don't forget to import lombo.jar as a library dependency.